# Internal Roller Brake Problem

Tags: brakes, drum-brakes

I have Shimano Inter M Roller Brakes on my bike. I felt the rear brakes were a bit light after riding 800 or so KM (total mileage on my bike so far) so I thought maybe theres a bit of cable stretch involved too but after I adjusted them, it feels the wheel is rubbing the brake and it has significant drag even when I walk the bike.

Are there any instructional links that help me to adjust roller brakes on the web or if anyone has experience with a set of instructions? I had followed a youtube video specifically for dutch bikes but only uses the barrell adjuster..I only utilized the adjustment barrell at the back but now I have tested it by loosening and tightening but it hasnt resolved the situation.

Thank You.

Comment: What if you disconnect the cable from the brake (there is quick, no tool disconnecting)? Still rubbing?

Comment: Took it to LBS and found the stand was rubbing against the wheel due to the wheel not true. Hopefully that resolves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: 800km seemed like a short time for those brakes to have problems. I LOVE those brakes. They did very well in the wet cold climes of the UK. Beyond a comment, some advice. They do need servicing, and it will feel like they are becoming less effective when that time comes. You'll have to take them to the LBS for regreasing (seriously, they use grease inside of them). Otherwise enjoy an excellent but under appreciated Shimano product.

Comment: Thank You. I did buy a grease only for internal roller brakes and put a pea size in the hole in the brake. I read somewhere that this should be done every 500K albeit at some point the brakes should be taken to a LBS for service to clean it all up. I appreciate your tip and advice.